# Speeding up Spark SQL Unit Tests

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

We are developing an application which mainly consists of a lot of Spark  SQL Jobs which read and write data from Cassandra.

In order to unit test, we create a fresh Cassandra Keyspace, insert data, execute the Job and then the read the result from Cassandra tables. So far so well. However these unit tests tend to take a lot of time (usually around 10-30sec per Job), although there is very little data to process.

Is there a possibility to speed up Spark in a way, that it doesn't loose correctness? (E.g. Disabling Optimizations).

What we are already doing:

- Using Cassandra on a Ram Drive. Pure Cassandra read and write is already very fast, also the Keyspace/Table recreation.
- Reusing Spark / Hive Context for different Jobs.

What I wouldn't like to do is to refactor the Jobs in a way, that we insert / output pure Data Frames, because then we don't know anyway that all Column Names and Column Types match the Cassandra ones.

Another Optimization would be, to make the unit tests bigger, so that one Spark Job Run would tests multiple aspects, but this somehow feels bad in terms of Unit Test design.

We are using Spark SQL 1.6.2 with Scala

Comment: I'd suggest that your unit test shouldn't include Cassandra every time.  I know you don't want to but instead use pure dataframes. And then test your interface with cassandra seperately. Also you shouldn't use your SparkContext across multiple jobs. I've found its speed up negligible and it creates (an admittedly minor) dependency between tests. Slightly unrelated but: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base is handy.

Comment: Yes. Maybe separating read and write from Cassandra and the testcase could indeed do something on performance

Regarding Spark Context Reuse: There are two problems, first is the long time, spark takes to ramp up, but more critical that you can't restart hive context within the same JVM: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10872

Comment: You can stop and start a new a spark context. You can't have two running at the same time. I do it in my code and the library I linked does the same and provides some handy tear down startup mehtods to sdo so. Also in my experience spark takes a couple of seonds to start locally.

Comment: In our experiments this worked well for Spark Context, but not for HiveContext as there is no shutdown/stop method and the next time you try to create it, it will fail with a Derby Exception (see ticket above).

Comment: I had some trouble with this locally too. I know the library contains a BaseTestWithDataframes class so that may do something clever. It looks like it uses an appid based on the current time and overwrites a lot of the config. However it is listed as experimental. Beyond this I don't know anymore unfortunately.